# Converting askerisks * to <strong> in php

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have the following problem:

```
$str = 'This is a *random* text, with some *bold* markup';

$bold_str = preg_replace('/\*(.*?)\*/','<strong>\\1</strong>',$str);

echo $bold_str
```

Now still echoes the contents of $str, as apparently nothing is replaced.
This would be the desired string:

```
$bold_str = 'This is a <strong>random</strong> text, with some <strong>bold</strong> markup'
```

Comment: your code works for me. Just add a semicolon at the end of echo $bold_str;

Comment: It definitely looks like it should work.

Comment: Why don't you just use two asterisks instead of one and use a Markdown library for PHP?

Comment: @Blender that is because only bold (and perhaps italic) should be possible to use. The rest of CMS uses markitup, which uses one * for bold, so it's nice to be consistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When i [load your code into codepad](http://codepad.org/eU0OcsFY) it works fine for me, so maybe you have another problem and failed to illustrate your actual code here.

However, I prefer to work with negative character expressions like in this example:

```
$str = 'This is a *random* text, with some *bold* markup';
$bold_str = preg_replace('/\*([^*]*)\*/','<strong>\\1</strong>',$str);
echo $bold_str;
```

This is just a matter of preference, but when your expressions grow and you start to tamper with the greedyness of your quantifiers / expression (like you already did with `.*?`) this can save you a lot of headache. This expression always has the same result - independent of the use of the ungreedy modifer `U`.

Comment: Did you test this? Because `[^*]` without any quantifier is not going to work. Also, why is it any better than the original attempt?

Comment: There was nothing wrong with that part of his code.

Comment: @Jon forgot the quantifier, right. Also, it's not really better than the original - only in respect to greedyness/ungreedyness. It produces the same result, independently of the greedyness of the quantifier and/or the whole expression.

Comment: Both work indeed. Thanks for that guys! Use it indeed in some bigger PHP code, where I missed an argument for a function to not directly echo the original string. Thanks for all